# Как подсчитать сумму букв самого короткого слова и самого длинного?

Tags: c#, winforms, строки

Есть строка в которой введены слова через пробел, как подсчитать суммарное количество букв самого маленького слова, и самого большого?

Мой код:

```
if(txtString.Text.Length!=0)
{
    str = txtString.Text.ToString();
}
for (int i = 0; i <str.Length; i++)
{
    if(str[i]==' ')
    {
        massstr[i] = a;
        b++;
        a = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        a++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
{
    if(max<massstr[i])
    {
        max = massstr[i];
        MessageBox.Show(""+max);
    }
    if(min>massstr[i])
    {
        min = massstr[i];
        MessageBox.Show("min "  + min);
    }
}
txtResString.Text = "Суммарное количество букв самого маленького и большого слова равно " + (min + max) + " ";
```

Comment: Молодец! В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Кажеться это задание задают всем подряд :) два похожих я видел точно.

Comment: @Igor Нужно найти в строке, считанной с текстбокса, самое маленькое слово, посчитать количество букв, тоже самое с самым большим словом, и прибавить количество букв самого маленького, к количеству самого большого. Мой код работает некорректно. Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: @Alex Если ваш код работает некорректно, то есть средства отладки. По сути у вас две задачи: разобрать строку на слова и подсчитать в каждом слове кол-во букв.

Comment: @ГеннадийП спасибо, додумался сам, было много лишнего массивы и тд. Всем спасибо!

Comment: На будущее: если ваш код работает некорректно, то нужно сразу написать в вопросе, что именно и как работает некорректно, а не ждать, пока ваш код посмотрят и скажут "хорошо, а в чём проблема-то?". Не рассчитывайте на телепатов, старайтесь задать понятный вопрос.

Comment: А разбить строку на массив и перебором найти `min` и `max` было бы проще. И строк кода было бы меньше.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к мнению @Rootware и хочу порекомендовать [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Классический вариант, как учат в школах:

```
public int SumOfShortestAndLenghtiestWord(string[] words)
{
    if (words.Length == 0)
        throw new Exception("N/a to empty array.");

    var min = 0;
    var max = 0;
    bool isFirstWord = true;

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (isFirstWord)
        {
            min = word.Length;
            max = word.Length;
            isFirstWord = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (word.Length > max)
            max = word.Length;

        if (word.Length < min)
            min = word.Length;
    }

    //min.Dump();
    //max.Dump();
    return min + max;
}
```

Допустим, в этом случае min = 2, max = 11 сумма - 13:

```
var source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua";
var result = SumOfShortestAndLenghtiestWord(source.Split(' '));
```

И этот вариант хорош тем, что обход слов совершается лишь один раз.

Можно также написать вариант на базе linq:

```
public int SumOfShortestAndLenghtiestWord(string[] words)
{
    if (words.Length == 0)
        throw new Exception("N/a to empty array.");

    var min = words.Min(x => x.Length);
    var max = words.Max(x => x.Length);

    return min + max;
}
```

Компактный, легко читаемый, можно ужать до однострочника.

Update. Тут в комментариях намекают, что самый каноничный вариант - это:

```
public int SumOfShortestAndLenghtiestWord(string[] words)
{
    if (words.Length == 0)
        throw new Exception("N/a to empty array.");

    var min = words[0].Length;
    var max = words[0].Length;

    for(var i = 1; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].Length > max)
            max = words[i].Length;

        if (words[i].Length < min)
            min = words[i].Length;
    }

    return min + max;
}
```

Comment: В школах учат `var max = words[0];` и потом `for (int i = 1; i < ...` флаг и дополнительное условие внутри цикла не нужны :)